Manga, about a group of friends who gained superpowers, and the mc who gained the power to control technology
I cannot remember much about this manga, but I'm this definitely sure that it wasn't an isekai, and that the main character had the ability to modify and control technology.

Hu, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it colour or black-and-white?

I don't remember when or where, I read the manga, only that it was in color
